# Get posts by language in Polylang plugin

Tags: get-posts, plugin-polylang

I use the [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) plugin to translate my website in Italian and German. How can I get the latest post in Italian?

I'm using the arguments below to get the content of the post, which afterwards I send via newsletter, but I don't know how to get the right language.

```
$args_menu = array (
    'post_type' => 'EXAMPLE',
    'order'=> 'DESC', 
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'suppress_filters' => false  
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the query_post function, I think you can just add the 'lang' parameter:

```
$args_menu = array (
   ...
   'lang' => 'it',
   ...
);
```

See : http://wp.primacom.cz/en/enplugins/how-to-display-posts-only-in-one-language-in-polylang-plugin/

Comment: You are a genius!!! lol... This is exactly what i need, thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked! Don't forget to mark this as solved ;) Regards